# Gimp - How To Apply Threshold Alpha To Many Images At Same Time

Tags: gimp

I've been upscaling images using ESRGAN and IEU Winform, and I am very satisfied with the results. My only problem is that some of the sprites I'm upscaling are partially transparent where they shouldn't be, and not fully transparent where they should be. 
Here's an example: [image: faded tree]
I'm pretty sure this could be fixed with a quick threshold alpha on all the sprites and then just small manual edits where needed. I know Gimp has some sort of scripting, but I don't really know how to use it

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Most likely much easier done with [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/index.php) in a shell script. Ask in StackOverfloxw with an `imagemagick` tag, or ask on the [ImageMagick forum](https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/).

Answer (score 0):

You could try XNconvert on the alpha channel image before merging. Adjusting the gammasat, black/white point, and slight blurring seemed to do the trick. That's what I use. Easy and has a GUI[image]